# Visual Studio 2010 mangles up command line parameters for "Start without debugging" for C# project -- it adds an extra caret, or ^

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, command-line

It took me a while to figure out why my `SSH` client that I was working on was refusing to connect to a server (only some of the times.)

Here's the command line specified in the VS2010 debugger window. Notice the `pwd` parameter password:

[image]

Then if I start debugging it in VS2010 and run this code:

```
for(int c = 0; c < args.Length; c++)
{
    if (args[c] == "pwd"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(args[c + 1]);
    }
}

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
```

It gives me the correct password:

[image]

But if I start it again from the VS2010 but without debugging, I get this (see extra caret):

[image]

WHY???

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080806-01/?p=21343

Comment: @HansPassant: So what do you do if you need to include it in a command line? Like in a password in this case.